# Porque no puedo llenar en las pocicion 0 y 24

Tags: c, struct

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
mi metodo main cuando llama en la pocision cero me causa error de que no tiene nungun valor, pero cuando llama desde la posición 1 a 23 me  muestra normal.

Esta forma de llenado que hice, ya lo realicé con otro struct no puse todo el código por que me dira que mi prugunta es puro código

```
#include "Funciones.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 
llenado();
printf("La naturaleza es: ", naturaleza[0].nombre);
}
```

mi cabecera

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

  //Consonante
 #define CANT_N 24


  void llenado();

 struct naturaleza{
   char *nombre;
}naturaleza[CANT_N];
```

archivo c datos

```
 #include "Funciones.h"
 void llenado(){
 naturaleza[0].nombre="Hasty  ";
 naturaleza[1].nombre="Lonely ";
 naturaleza[2].nombre="Mild   ";
 naturaleza[3].nombre="Impish ";
 naturaleza[4].nombre="Jolly  ";
 naturaleza[5].nombre="Rash   ";
 naturaleza[6].nombre="Gentle ";
 naturaleza[7].nombre="Brave  ";
 naturaleza[8].nombre="Careful";
 naturaleza[9].nombre="Docile ";
 naturaleza[10].nombre="Adamant";
 naturaleza[11].nombre="Lax    ";
 naturaleza[12].nombre="Hardy  ";
 naturaleza[13].nombre="Sassy  ";
 naturaleza[14].nombre="Naive  ";
 naturaleza[15].nombre="Quiet  ";
 naturaleza[16].nombre="Timid  ";
 naturaleza[17].nombre="Modest ";
 naturaleza[18].nombre="Bold   ";
 naturaleza[19].nombre="Naughty";
 naturaleza[20].nombre="Relaxed";
 naturaleza[21].nombre="Quirky ";
 naturaleza[22].nombre="Calm   ";
 naturaleza[23].nombre="Serious";*/
 naturaleza[24].nombre="Bashful";

 }
```

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y poner, por favor, el mensaje de error completo que te da cuando intentas leer la posición cero?

Comment: Por favor, pon el código que utilizas para visualizar los valores de `naturaleza`

Comment: @Alfabravo no muestra mensaje  pero alli coloque un screen

Comment: esta al iinicio donde esta mi main de esa manera lo muestro con el printf

Comment: Si la matriz tiene 24 posiciones, estas van de 0 a 23, por eso no podrás usar la posición 24, pero deberías poder usar la 0.

Answer (score 3):

Estás declarando un array con 24 posiciones:

```
 #define CANT_N 24

 struct naturaleza{
   char *nombre;
}naturaleza[CANT_N];
```

Pero después rellenas **25** ¿Por qué?

```
 void llenado(){
 naturaleza[0].nombre="Hasty  ";    //  1
 naturaleza[1].nombre="Lonely ";    //  2
 naturaleza[2].nombre="Mild   ";    //  3
 naturaleza[3].nombre="Impish ";    //  4
 naturaleza[4].nombre="Jolly  ";    //  5
 naturaleza[5].nombre="Rash   ";    //  6
 naturaleza[6].nombre="Gentle ";    //  7
 naturaleza[7].nombre="Brave  ";    //  8
 naturaleza[8].nombre="Careful";    //  9
 naturaleza[9].nombre="Docile ";    // 10
 naturaleza[10].nombre="Adamant";   // 11
 naturaleza[11].nombre="Lax    ";   // 12
 naturaleza[12].nombre="Hardy  ";   // 13
 naturaleza[13].nombre="Sassy  ";   // 14
 naturaleza[14].nombre="Naive  ";   // 15 
 naturaleza[15].nombre="Quiet  ";   // 16
 naturaleza[16].nombre="Timid  ";   // 17
 naturaleza[17].nombre="Modest ";   // 18
 naturaleza[18].nombre="Bold   ";   // 19
 naturaleza[19].nombre="Naughty";   // 20
 naturaleza[20].nombre="Relaxed";   // 21
 naturaleza[21].nombre="Quirky ";   // 22
 naturaleza[22].nombre="Calm   ";   // 23
 naturaleza[23].nombre="Serious";*/ // 24
 naturaleza[24].nombre="Bashful";   // 25

 }
```

Lo único que consigues con esto es escribir *fuera* de los límites del array, es decir, estás escribiendo en posiciones de memoria que no pertenecen al array sino que ahí puede estar almacenada cualquier otra variable.

Lo que suceda a partir de ese momento es indeterminado.

Empieza por borrar la asignación número 25 y comprueba si, por arte de magia, todo vuelve a funcionar como esperas.

Si no se solucionan todos los problemas deberías editar la pregunta y añadir un ejempló mínimo y completo que reproduzca tu problema.

Comment: Gracias si que es difícil aprender un lenguaje solo , usaba mal la asignación de posiciones, asigne de la misma manera a otro `struct` por eso salía error el espacio de memoria se puso en este `struct`